# Should I include "prefix-free" plugin in my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) is a cool plugin by Lea Verou. It helps the developer to write CSS3 selectors with no prefix. I wonder if it is worthy to include it in my site.

I have a website with some CSS3 and I want to know if loading a JS file that changes the CSS after page loads may decrease my pages' render speed and affect the client side performance?

Comment: Mostly properties, but also selectors sometimes (like `::-moz-selection`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course will the execution of a Javascript altering you CSS decrease the performance of your Site, both in terms of javascript-execution time and (re-)rendering-speed of you site.

It is very costly to let javascript examine and alter all your CSS. I prefer such preprocessors like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which let you write prefix-free CSS and produce the according prefixed CSS before delivering it to the client. Of course this has the drawback of having bigger css-files to transfer, but still this is the solution I prefer.

You don't need to write the necessary mixins for yourself, there are basically countless extensions, that will do the work for you and provide ready-to-use mixins.

Just out of the top of my head: for less, one could use http://lessprefixer.com/ - for Sass http://compass-style.org/

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to check how each of the solutions affects my site performance

Comment: How to use less to make prefixed version of css

Comment: @MuhammadUmer By using according mixins that add the necessary prefixed automatically. An example would be http://lessprefixer.com/ I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can expect decrease in page load time and possibly [FOUC](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/).

If you don't want to compromise end-user experience I would recommend you to use tools such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). Less enables you to write more compact, managable css markup that gets transformed to regular css before sending from server to client. It will easily handle css-prefix problem.

Comment: I've seen -prefix-free to cause FOUC on Chrome. *A lot.*