# Express: how to generate browser specific css at app startup once and serve it

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, less

Problem: I don't want to send prefixfree.js to client each time, i think it may not be good for speed and can be solved at server side.

But at the same time i don't want server to redo the same work over and over again. I want serer to do this:

when server is started...

1. Convert less to css
2. make 4 versions of all css files:

   1. webkit
   2. moz
   3. ie
   4. all browsers
3. then serve them appropriately, so if browser agent is webkit, serve webkit version of that css file. and if can't be determined then serve the all version.

Now i could serve the all file instead, and i know it won't add that much to the size of file. But i don't know how to make less compiler output a prefixed version and i don't want to go each css file in command line and run some command to add prefixes. Also, isn't a good practice to try to improve the flow as much as possible.

I could also use some ide plugin to add prefixes in less file, but that makes css files huge and hard to debug.

Comment: [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer).

Comment: can you tell what does it do, from what i get it takes final css and prefix it with all browsers prefixes right?

Comment: Well, it's available in almost any shell format including [`lessc` plugin](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix) (so you can apply it whenever you need to whatever you need. For instance if `Grunt` is a part of your build chain it's more flexible to use it as a [Grunt plugin](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer) instead of the mentioned `lessc` plugin).

Answer (score 1):

To make the right decision you should find out which browsers you have to support. Yous should also consider [Graceful degradation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement).

Personal i think running Less with the autoprefix and clean-css is a safe choice in most situations.

Testing is simple:

```
npm install less
npm install less-plugin-clean-css
npm install less-plugin-autoprefix
lessc source.less production.css --autoprefix --clean-css
```

Notice that you can set your target browsers as an argument for the  autoprefix plugin. To support the same browsers as Bootstrap does use the following:

```
 --autoprefix='Android 2.3','Android >= 4','Chrome >= 20','Firefox >= 24','iOS >= 6','Opera >= 12','Safari >= 6'
```

You are right. Vendor prefixes will make your CSS file larger. You should notice you can compress / minify your code (also zip) and you code can be cached by the browser.

You should compare the larger code with -prefix-fee; 2kb gziped an extra http process and some JavaScript processing. Vera explains why using it can be a good idea at: http://css-tricks.com/five-questions-with-lea-verou/

You idea is somewhere between the above two solutions. You css code is possible a little smaller, but you still will need some JavaScript processing to find out the browser of the user.

> I could also use some ide plugin to add prefixes in less file, but that > makes css files huge and hard to debug.

You can use the autoprefix plugin together with CSS sourcemap for easy debugging (use the --source-map option of the Less compiler). In most situations you will have a develop and production version of your code.

As already made clear by @seven-phases-max you can integrate all the above in a build chain with Grunt or Gulp.

Comment: i was thinking that express could use user agent to determine the browser then serve specific file `moz-home.css`, and if there is uncertainty then just serve the whole thing. `home.css` which could have prefixed versions or it could be with prefixfree.. I had forgotten about gzip and minifying, and source maps too. I think less compiler does compress if told to.

I have always felt using prefixfree in browsers is against best practices. It's like creating unnecessary weak point, which slows down the loading time. (first download prefix if not cached, 2nd analyze stylesheets, 3rd modify them)

Comment: yes Less has the `--compress` option which remove whitespace. One should prefer clean-css for better  optimizations such as selector merging.  Also prefix free can load from CDN. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947861/should-i-include-prefix-free-plugin-in-my-website confirms using prefix-free being bad practice. I think you can only judge when knowing the real bottleneck. For instance what is the overhead when using jQuery on your site too.